# How to wrap content - including images - around a responsive CSS sidebar

Tags: html, css, css-float, sidebar

Here's the layout I'm trying to achieve:

[image]

My content currently is a series of basic, block HTML elements (`h[1-5]`, `p`, `ul`, etc.) contained in a `div`, and if possible I'd like to keep them that way. All of the images are inside their own `p` in order to responsively resize

I've been able to add a `div style="float:right"` to the top of the content which creates the sidebar and wraps "normal" text content around it - specifically the first paragraph in my diagram above. However, the img, which is set to 100% does not wrap, it flows below the sidebar.

So really, I want images to have one of two widths - either 100%-width(sidebar) if the top of the image "should be" above the bottom of the sidebar, or 100% if the top of the image is below the bottom of the sidebar.

I can of course manually set the width on an image when debugging a page, to a value less than 100%-width(sidebar) and it jumps right up into place, so clearly the browser knows what that size is to not "push" the image down below the sidebar...

Here's the actual page where I'd like to get this to work; note that the first image is below the sidebar:

https://adventuretaco.com/?p=3655&draftsforfriends=kIq7mVDhNtCSklITGCJs2HAcE9xuPX8d

additionally, here is the CSS and HTML that I currently have for the post content:

CSS

```
p {
    margin: 0 0 1.25em 0;
}

ol, ul {
    margin: 0 1.5em 1.25em 1.5em;
}

.full-width-container {
    width: 100%;
}

.full-width-container img {
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: 0.5s;
}

.full-width-container img.flickrPhoto {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: 0.5s;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="post-content">
<p>As you may recall, we'd just cancelled our flight home due to the unknowns of Covid-19, but were still in exploration mode as we entered the Valley of Fire State Park in southeastern Nevada.</p>
<p id="photoContainer132" class="full-width-container"><img id="photo132" class="flickrPhoto" src="https://live.staticflickr.com/65535/49714173358_d19b1c2e70_n.jpg" /></p>
<p>Our trip to the Valley of Fire was somewhat opportunistic to say the least. A year before this trip ever even crossed my mind, I'd seen a photo on Flickr that had caught my eye. Sharp as ever, I completely forgot to save the photo or a link to the photo <img src="https://www.tacomaworld.com/styles/default/my/smilies/annoyed_gaah.gif" />, but - luckily for me - the photo had been geotagged <em>and</em> I'd saved a point of interest in my Google Earth map of Nevada. I'd noticed that point as I'd planned this trip, and mapped out the route, excited to see what nature had in store. So yeah, apparently, I'm not <em>always</em> as dumb as I look. <img src="https://www.tacomaworld.com/styles/default/my/smilies/original/wink.png" /> In researching Valley of Fire, I also discovered a second hike -rumored to have petroglyphs - and since it was on our way to the main attraction, we decided to stop off there first.</p>
<p id="photoContainer133" class="full-width-container"><img id="photo133" class="flickrPhoto" src="https://live.staticflickr.com/65535/49715029457_a61cffc61b_n.jpg" /></p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so after a bunch more research, trial and error, I've come to the conclusion that the answer to this question is that it cannot be solved with CSS / layout alone.

In the end, incorporated Javascript to solve the problem. It's not perfect - if images have been downsized to flow around the sidebar, then when the browser window gets larger, they don't get *larger* as ideally as they could.

Here's where I ended up; working sample at (scroll down here to see the sidebar)
https://adventuretaco.com/hidden-valleys-secret-tinaja-mojave-east-5/#photoContainer190

```
// start shortly after page is rendered
setTimeout(resizeImagesForFacebookEmbed, 500);

function resizeImagesForFacebookEmbed() {
    var tryAgain = true;

    // find each of the elements that make up the post, and iterate through each of them
    var content = jQuery('div.post-content').children().each(function () {
        if (this.tagName.toLowerCase() == 'p') {
            var firstChild = this.firstChild;
            var firstElementChild = this.firstElementChild;

            if (firstChild != null && firstChild == this.firstElementChild && firstElementChild.tagName.toLowerCase() == 'img') {
                var pRect = this.getBoundingClientRect();
                var imgRect = firstChild.getBoundingClientRect();

                var difference = imgRect.top - pRect.top;

                // if the image contained in the p is not at the top of the p, then make it smaller
                // so it will fit next to the embed, which is 350px wide
                if (difference > 25 || imgRect.width < (pRect.width - 400)) {

                    var sidebarLeft = document.getElementById("fbSidebar").getBoundingClientRect().left;
                    var imgLeft = firstChild.getBoundingClientRect().left;
                    var imgWidth = (sidebarLeft - imgLeft) * .95;

                    firstChild.style.width = imgWidth + "px";
                    tryAgain = false;
                    setTimeout(resizeImagesForFacebookEmbed, 1000);

                } else {
                    // do nothing
                }
            }
        }
    });

    if (tryAgain)
        setTimeout(resizeImagesForFacebookEmbed, 1000);
}

var waitForFinalEvent = (function () {
    var timers = {};
    return function (callback, ms, uniqueId) {
        if (!uniqueId) {
            uniqueId = "Don't call this twice without a uniqueId";
        }
        if (timers[uniqueId]) {
            clearTimeout(timers[uniqueId]);
        }
        timers[uniqueId] = setTimeout(callback, ms);
    };
})();

// handle window resize event to re-layout images
jQuery(function () {
    jQuery(window).resize(function () {
        waitForFinalEvent(function () {
            resizeImagesForFacebookEmbed();
        }, 500, "atFbEmbedId"); // replace with a uniqueId for each use
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you first need to downsize a little your images, due to their size, it becomes a little difficult to manipulate them within the scope of what you would like to do. You can alter them inside the  tag, or from the css file.  Then after, you can use inside of that code a "float: left;" in the .full-width-container img, give it a margin that should put them side to side.

Comment: the image sizes are already manipulated by the CSS to a 100% width (as I want them in the page). It's just that I don't want images pushed down by the sidebar. The key isn't about floating individual images left, either (I believe) because floating them left still pushes them below the sidebar, and out of the flow of the text, which I want to preserve.

Comment: Yeah, it will be that way since you want 100% width on them, it will keep pushing them down. Looking over on your page, you have a container that is not wide enought to keep them both side to side. Only  two choices I can think of are: 1)do an 80% width on your top image only, or 2) make your container bigger(instead of 100%, you can use pixels ). Hope this helps

Comment: So, I'd be OK making the top image narrower...but is there a way to make it narrower in a way that it is responsive to different resolutions? On some monitors it would be 80%, on others it would be 50%, etc...

Comment: There is a way to make it responsive, you will have to leave a width, and add pixels size to the css rules. I have left you a link on how to do it, it might help you more if you visualize it https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_image_responsive.asp

Comment: Yeah, thanks @josep408. Adding max-width is likely the way to get it done, but the problem is that max-width changes as images flow around the sidebar... so I can't just set max-width on all the images, because they will ALL end up narrower in that case, not just the ones by the sidebar.